# How to implement a database for email list

Tags: database, email, system-design

I am trying to make a newsletter system with a database storing an email list

My raw design of the schema is simply:

```
primary_key, subscribe_name, email
```

However, to avoid issues of bouncing/complaining and unclean email list, I am planning on several possibilities:

Plan A: add a verification process (aka send an email for them to click to make their account verified)

```
primary_key, subscribe_name, email, verified
```

More ambitious version: if not verified within two days, then the email will be automatically removed from the database:

Should I do:

DB1 (unverified email):

```
primary_key, subscribe_name, email, expiry_date
```

with DB2 (verified email): (then every time when I send a newsletter I am simply querying a clean database)

```
primary_key, subscribe_name, email
```

Or just combined:

```
primary_key, subscribe_name, email, verified, expiry_date
```

The issue with this is I don't know if it is possible to set a conditional ttl for expiry_date so it only gets removed if unverified

However, it seems like extra frictions to make user verify their identity when subscribing newsletter - hence:

Plan B: maybe it is better to just let the emails be in the list and remove as emails have higher bouncing/complain rate

```
primary_key, subscribe_name, email, status
```

Status is whether the email is a deliverable one - though I ain't sure what metric should be used to measure and what is the threshold I should use to kick an email out of my subscription list.

For reference, I am using AWS SES to implement it, and the data is in CockroachDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using double opt-in is always the best way when dealing with email subscriptions. Since you are using CockroachDB, you can use [Row-Level TTL](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/row-level-ttl) and provide an expression that combines the expire date and a verified Boolean field. You can set the default value of the expire date to now() + Interval() so it will be populated automatically.

Full disclosure, I work at CockroachDB but I also used to work for a couple email companies. If this sounds good, I can follow up with some sample code.

Comment: Yes, sample code will be very helpful! Thank you

Comment: To follow up, may I ask the exact implementation that allows me to combine both the TTL and the boolean field?

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late response.
You should be able to default the expire date (expire_date) to something like:

`"NOW() + INTERVAL '30 day'"`

You can change the interval to however long.

Then you can enable row-level TTL on the table like this:

`ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS some_table SET (ttl_expiration_expression = 'IF(NOT verified, expire_date, null)');`

Here's a [blogpost](www.cockroachlabs.com) you can check out.